# Extract exact text in tags

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to extract the text embedded between a tag e.g. I want to get the text "TEST" from

```
"&lt;"Subject"&gt;" TEST "&lt;/"Subject"&gt;"
```

I have used First

```
RegexMatch /(&lt;Subect&gt;).*(&lt;/Subject&gt;)/i)
```

but get an error

> "/ An unescaped delimiter must be escaped with a backslash ()".

Any help on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I may be missing something, but can't you simply use `innerHTML`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: isn't your error self explaining?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with a regex, you have to escape '/' (with a preceding '\') if it's part of your search string

```js
    s = '"<"Subject">" TEST "</"Subject">"';
    console.log(s.replace(/"<"Subject">"(.*)"<\/"Subject">"/, '$1'))
```